# Can't rename response in redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

I want to rename response in `.then(...` because it's called the same as parameter,  but getting

```
[1] ./src/actions/postsActions.js
[1]   Line 95:  'e' is not defined  no-undef
```

The problem is that it `dispatches action` that show the message, and it takes `addPost` parameter data as `showMessage` parameter, and there is no message property in it..

Example:

```
export const addPost = data => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_POST
  });
  fetch(API_URL + "/posts", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")),
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      e =>
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_POST_SUCCESS,
          payload: e
        }),
      dispatch(showMessage(e)),
      setTimeout(() => {
        history.push("/");
        dispatch({ type: CLEAR_MESSAGE });
      }, 2000)
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_POST_FAILED,
        payload: err
      })
    );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead `ecma6` implicit `return`, add a block statement.

No need of `return` there.Separate the statement with semicolon.

```
then(e => {

      dispatch({type: ADD_POST_SUCCESS, payload: e});
      dispatch(showMessage(e));
      setTimeout(() => {
        history.push("/");
        dispatch({type: CLEAR_MESSAGE});
      }, 2000);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this code below, when you chain the multiple functions in `then`. The reference break

```
Promise.resolve(1)
.then(
  e => 
    console.log(e), 
    console.log(e) // this will give an error, as e is not accessible here
)
```

Either you have to wrap everything in one block like others suggested or if the order of execution matters, you can do something like this

```
Promise.resolve(1)
.then(e => {
  console.log('1. ' + e); // first function
  return e;
})
.then(e => {
  console.log('2. ' + e); // second function
  return e;
})
```